# Language locale not getting added to URL

Tags: multilingual, habitat

After configuring the sitecore Habitat based on the instruction from GIThub, we could see sometimes locale code is getting added and not added to the URL.

This is happening inconsistently.But the content are loading as expected.

Both below URL are working fine

http://habitat.dev.local/en/About-Habitat/Getting-Started

http://habitat.dev.local/About-Habitat/Getting-Started

The same is happening EN and DA locale. 
Is there a way to show the locale code permanently in the URL

Comment: Find `LinkProvider` in `sitecore.config` file. There is `languageEmbedding`. Set it to true;

Comment: Yes. This works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is controlled by the `languageEmbedding` attribute on your `linkManager`.

By default, Sitecore adds the language code to your URLs `asNeeded`. Which is a bit fuzzy; but essentially Sitecore should add it when it isn't sure of your current `Context.Language` and wants to make sure the URL points to the desired result.

Other options are:

- Always (always enforce language in the url, this is what you ask for)
- Never

You can find the configuration in your `Sitecore.Config` located under `App_Include`.

```
  <!-- Options (first is default):
           addAspxExtension: false | true (If you set this to false, remember to configure IIS to map all requests (*) to ASP.NET)
           alwaysIncludeServerUrl: false | true
           encodeNames: true | false
           languageEmbedding: asNeeded | always | never
           languageLocation: filePath | queryString
           lowercaseUrls: true | false
           shortenUrls: true | false
           useDisplayName: false | true
    -->
  <linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="asNeeded" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
    </providers>
  </linkManager>
```

It is **not** recommended practice to modify this file directly however. I recommend you implement any changes as a Sitecore Config Patch file. Described many places, for instance in [Create a Sitecore LinkProvider to use different LinkManager](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/change-linkmanager-config/).

Comment: yes. this works